# How to use reference wrapping for a thread involving a member function of user defined class returning a non void type(c++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, future

I'm having trouble making the wait/get future mechanism work with a member function of user defined class returning a non-void type.

I wrote a very simple example below, the reference wrapping inside the instruction

```
std::future<int> fut = std::async( &BasicClass::funcInt, std::ref(anObject) );
```

fails at compile time

```
#include <iostream> // cout
#include <future>   // async, future

using std::cout;
using std::async;
using std::future;

class BasicClass
{ public:
    int funcInt(){return 119;}
    void funcVoid(){cout << "\nvoid funcVoid()";}
};

int main()
{
  BasicClass anObject;

  std::thread thread1( &BasicClass::funcVoid, std::ref(anObject));
  thread1.join();

  std::future<int> fut = std::async( &BasicClass::funcInt, std::ref(anObject));
  fut.wait();
  int a = fut.get();
  return 0;
}
```

The reference wrapping works find for a thread with a member function returning a void type works fine.

```
  std::thread thread1( &BasicClass::funcVoid, std::ref(anObject));
```

Can you explain the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is the compiler error ?

Comment: You tagged this as C++11, I'd strongly recommend you use `auto` more in your code; it makes everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magical pseudo-function [`INVOKE`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) that `std::async` (among other things) uses doesn't handle pointers-to-member paired with `reference_wrapper`s. `std::thread` is also supposed to use `INVOKE`, but libstdc++ (GCC's standard library)'s implementation happens to not choke on this particular combination, due to the way it was implemented. libc++, Clang's standard library, will fail to compile for both.

Until [LWG issue 2219](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2219)'s resolution is voted into the working paper and implemented, just use a pointer:
`std::async(&BasicClass::funcInt, &anObject);`

Comment: Is it known to work with non trivial class?

I implemented a template queue where pop returns a T*.
I've tested it in single thread, it works(seems to work) fine, I can push, pop, dereference the returned pointers.
Now, after pushing an element to the queue, I pop it using a future(there should be no multi-threading related issue), the pointer returned is not nullptr but when I try to assign/dereference it, I get a Segmentation fault at runtime.
Note that I  tried adding the -pthread option when compiling. I'm using g++ 4.9.2 in a cygwin environment

Comment: @stackoverflower Yes, assuming that lifetime issues are handled correctly. Please post a separate question with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).