# segmentation fault at runtime using future c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

I am getting a segmentation fault on the commented instruction at the end of the code snippet during runtime.
Did I use properly the future? The queue works(seems to work) fine in single thread. When I try popping the element asynchronously, I get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <assert.h>
using std::cout;

template<typename T>
class Queue
{ private:
    struct element
    {
      T data;
      element* previous;
      element():previous(nullptr){}
    };

    std::atomic<element*> head;
    std::atomic<element*> tail;
  public:
    Queue():head(new element), tail( head.load() ){}

    ~Queue()
    {
      while( element* const old_head = head.load() )
      {
        head.store(old_head->previous);
        delete old_head;
      }
    }

    T* pop()
    {
      element* old_head = head.load();
      if( old_head == tail.load() ){return nullptr;}

      head.store( old_head->previous );

      T* const result = new T(old_head->data);
      delete old_head;
      return result;
    }

    void push(T new_value)
    {
      element* new_data = new element;
      new_data->data = new_value;

      element* const old_tail = tail.load();
      std::swap(old_tail->data, new_value);

      element* p = new element;
      old_tail -> previous = p;
      tail.store(p);
      assert( tail.load() != head.load() );
    }

 };

int main()
{
  Queue<double> aDoubleQueue;

  assert( nullptr == aDoubleQueue.pop() );
  aDoubleQueue.push(17.0);
  assert( 17.0 == *aDoubleQueue.pop() );
  aDoubleQueue.push(17.0);
  aDoubleQueue.push(19.0);
  assert( 17.0 == *aDoubleQueue.pop() );
  assert( 19.0 == *aDoubleQueue.pop() );
  assert( nullptr == aDoubleQueue.pop() );

  aDoubleQueue.push(17.0);
  std::future< double* > popped = std::async(&Queue<double>::pop, &aDoubleQueue );
  popped.wait();  
  if( nullptr == popped.get()){ cout << "\n nullptr";}
  else
  { cout << "\n !nullptr";
    // double* a = popped.get(); // causes a segmentation fault
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a debugging service. Maybe a proper debugger can help you find *where* the segfault occurs. Also, you seem to be using pointers in multiple threads. That is a race condition waiting to happen...

Comment: Your queue is not thread safe at all, if you pop from more than one thread, you'll get deleted pointers. (You can find working implementation of lock free queues easily on Google). That doesn't explain the segmentation fault for only one pop though.

Comment: std::atomic members don't guarantee the class is thread safe. The immediate reason of the segfault is that you can't call `get` twice in a row.

Comment: I'm having issue with the future grammar with non trivial cases, I've been ask to generate a separate MCVE [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553262/how-to-use-reference-wrapping-for-a-thread-involving-a-member-function-of-user-d/31553922?noredirect=1#comment51067093_31553922).

I'm not trying to make it thread safe now. I don't understand the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [std::future::get()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/get/) say

> this member function shall be called once at most for every future

You call it twice by which time it's invalid. It throws an exception which you don't handle.

Comment: Nope, not an exception. **Undefined Behavior** (C++14 § 30.6.6/3: 

_"The effect of calling any member function other than the destructor, the move-assignment operator, or `valid` on a `future` object for which
`valid() == false` is undefined"_. After calling `get()` once, `valid()` returns `false`.)

Comment: VS2013 throws an exception

Comment: The note right after the quoted section recommends it (*Note: Implementations are encouraged to detect this case and throw an object of type `future_error` with an error condition of `future_errc::no_state`. — end note*), but notes are not normative. Most implementations will throw an exception, but they don't have to. In fact, they could format your hard drive instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to cppreference, `valid` is `false` after call to `future::get()` method. Second call causes exception to be thrown because `valid` is set to `false` after first call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to futures too. So I may be off.
Do you need the poppedc.wait()?

My understanding is that popped.get would automatically wait.

As was pointed out, you shouldn't call get twice. My temptation is to put a breakpoint on the second get and single step into the code to see the segfault.  I will bet anything the get tries to return a pointer to data that has already been deleted.

Your use to Queue is treadsafe, but dangerous. The simplest to explain is that there is no interleaving of accesses to the queue in the thread.

Response to hit.
No. Thread 1 runs till it starts thread two, thread one then stops immediately. thread 2, then runs to completion. Then thread 1 starts up again. There can be no race condition because the flow will not allow it.

Comment: It's not threadsafe, though. In `push`, if thread 1 modifies the tail (`old_tail`), the same object can be modified by another thread (both load the same pointer from `tail`) before `push` stores things back. The best-case scenario is that one of the calls to `push` is ignored. Worst-case? Race condition, undefined behavior etc.